# Create folders inside currently selected folder using batch

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm trying to use batch (via context menu) to create folders inside the currently selected folder in Explorer. I've got the script *mostly* working: the context menu command runs as expected, and the folders are created. Only instead of being created inside the selected subfolder, they're created in the parent of that subfolder.

I've tried using both %cd% and %1% for the folder path, with the same result: the folders are created in the parent folder of the folder that's currently selected,a not in the folder itself. How do I tell batch to put the folders in the proper place?

My code so far (batch):

```
md %1
md Assets
md Assets/Client_Input
md Working_Files
md Output
```

(Registry)

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\ClientProjectStructure]
@="Client Project Structure"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\ClientProjectStructure\command]
@="\"C:\\Users\\[USERNAME]\\Documents\\Batch_Files\\client_folder_structure.bat\" \"%1\""
```

Comment: Insert a `cd %1` after `md %1`

Comment: What does the context menu command look like?

Comment: @Aacini didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: @Compo just updated the question with the registry code.

Comment: If you right click on a directory and select that context menu entry, it will transfer the full path to that directory as `%1`. So I'm assuming that you should replace the first line `md %1` with `cd /d %1`. You can also get rid of the second line as that directory will be created as part of the third line. Although in the third line you should replace / with \ in that line

Comment: In the reg file I'd replace in the last line ` \"%1\"" `  with ` \"%~1\""` I think if the path contains spaces it will already be supplied with enclosing double quotes.

Comment: @Compo that did it! Thank you very much. :)

Comment: The command `md "Assets\Client_Input"` creates both directories at once, so you do not need to create `Assets` first (supposing that command extensions are enabled, which is the default anyway)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
@Echo off
SetLocal
PushD "%~1"
For %%A in (
  Assets Assets/Client_Input Working_Files Output 
) Do MD "%__CD__%%%A"
PopD
```

Comment: This also works! I ended up using Compo's solution in the comments because it didn't require much change to my existing code, but this one did do the trick. Thank you!